# mini_magick initialize error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, sinatra, minimagick

i'm experiencing strange behaviour with minimagick

Everything works fine on every develop workations but
in production i get this:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

If i execute

```
service nginx restart
```

I get

```
ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```

only one time. Every future reload of the page i get the arguments error.

Here's the code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'mini_magick'

get '/test' do    
  MiniMagick::Image.open("/webapps/myapp/testimg.png")  
end
```

if i execute convert:

```
# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-03-20 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): xml zlib
```

Any idea?